# If I capture a return value in an auto&, will that be destroyed from under me?

Tags: c++

Take the following code:

```
const std::string GetString()
{
    return std::string();
}

auto& thisIsANewString = GetString();
```

What happens in this scenario?  It compiles successfully, but does the `auto` reference keep the string around?  Or does it get destroyed and I'm left with an orphaned reference?

The reason I'm giving this a go is to maintain the `const` on the return value, whereas just doing a straight `auto` usage takes a copy.

Comment: you return a string which you created, so thisIsANewString is referencing that. Once that reference is gone the string is destroyed. If instead of & you would write * and returning a newly allocated object then it would not feel so strange or?

Comment: I had a strong feeling that was the case, but I'm not nearly as familiar with the rules around references compared to pointers.

Comment: yeah sometimes C++ makes you fundamentally rethink things :) but in this particular case, if that didn't work then a lot of C++ code would be broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens in this scenario?

The reference is bound to a temporary object, and the lifetime of the temporary object is extended to match the lifetime of the reference.

This is useful in templates where you will be able to treat references, and objects that are reference wrappers equally. It's only confusing to use temporary lifetime extension outside of templates, but it is allowed.

> whereas just doing a straight auto usage takes a copy.

Just to clarify, there are zero copies in this program:

```
std::string GetString()
{
    return {};
}

auto thisIsANewString = GetString();
```

... at least since C++17. Prior to that, there is technically a move that compilers are allowed, but not required to optimise away. Prior to C++11 there is technically a copy that compilers are allowed, but not required to optimise away.

Comment: Oops, I know about FRO but was imprecise in my terminology.  A fundamental sin for C++!